# Why was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I'm just curious, beyond the loss of 65 points.

[Bayes' Theorem question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/341708/probability-of-tossing-coins)

Comment: I think the comment by Manoj Pandey should explain it.

Comment: I saw that comment and it explains very little.  Was the problem intellectual property of Brilliant?  Did the OP violate a copyright in posting the problem?

Comment: A more accurate explanation is in here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6624/deleted-questions?rq=1
I agree with the sentiment.  That said, it is patently unfair to those who answer the post to lose their points.  Math.SE should not be responsible for such behavior, and sanctions should be between the OP and the contest provider, in this case, Brilliant.  I do understand, though, that Math.SE should not become a refuge for cheaters.  Is that what was being done here?

Comment: @Ron: in cases like this, usually the moderator who deleted the question would re-instate the question after the deadline is up for the contest (in this case, sometime next week). So it is usually not deleted for good. This however requires the moderator to remember to undelete the question ... it would help if you remind us about it.

Comment: @WillieWong: thanks, will do.

Comment: And also note what Qiaochu and Nick wrote in the comments in the meta post you linked to: there's not even complete consensus among the moderators about what to do. Some of us prefer to lock instead of delete, some of us the other way around. YMMV depending on who's reading flags at a given time.

Comment: @WillieWong, note that Calvin Lin is both active on MSE and a prominent employee of Brilliant. Perhaps he could be persuaded to post something here.

Comment: @RonGordon: The deletion was only temporary, and I have now reinstated the question since the week is over.

Comment: @EricNaslund: many thanks.  I now get it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks Will Jagy.

This is indeed a Brilliant problem which was just released this week, as Manoj Pandey pointed out. You can view it [here](https://brilliant.org/i/c6vRPk/). I have not come across it on MathSE, otherwise would have made a comment.

The understanding that I have, is that when I spot a problem posed by Brilliant, I would make a flag / request for moderation, and have the moderators lock the problem (just the discussion) for a week.

I do not ask that discussions be deleted, though I would request for individual posters to 'hide' their posts for a week.

I was not involved in the decision to delete the mentioned post.

I would be in the Math chat room for the next half hour, if you have any comments / concerns.

Comment: Good. I know you had not seen this one. I cannot be sure, maybe you meant "I do not ask that discussions be deleted" because your next word is "though." Let's see, I am strongly against people putting contest/Project Euler/whatever problems on MSE, I'm not generally all that comfortable with homework, as the opportunities for detailed tutoring are quite limited in this format.

Comment: @WillJagy The "I do ask" that was a typo which I quickly corrected when reviewing my reply.

Comment: Thanks, Calvin. i am pretty far on the end of the spectrum as being against cheating; I already know that not all the moderators see it my way. But I like the idea of someone from one of these other sites saying "You know, we'd rather you curtailed this." There is sometimes, on MSE, too much "This is our site, we don't need to care about the interests of anyone running any other site or assigning problems anywhere."

Comment: @WillJagy There is a big difference between dealing with a community, and dealing with a entity. Whatever course of action I request, someone in the community will object to it (derive from "you can't please everyone"). As you mentioned, different moderators have their own opinions about the proper course of action to take, and SE has no clear guideline to follow. I am glad that most decide to lock the most for a week. With other Q&A sites where we communicate directly with the main personnel, we often get the post taken down almost immediately (within 1 business day).

Answer (score 6):

I asked Calvin Lin to respond, maybe he will notice my comment. For his benefit,

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

[image]

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=